# Append text in html <script></script> tag. Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I want to add text to a span container on runtime by calling a javascript function into the HTML node like so :

```
<span class="muted">
   <script>
       //Here I want to add the string returned to outer span. (I also use jinja tags) 
       getGenericObjName("{{n.news_type}}",{{n.news.object_id}});
   </script>
</span>
```

The reason I do this is because I iterate over a news feed. And i know that the function returns the correct value.

I also tried to use document.write(...) but it seems to override the whole page.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is your script tag in there? are you sure that script tags CAN be inside span tags?

Comment: are you trying to inject a script into a page?

Comment: I did not expect to get downvoted as I did not know it looked like code injection. But anyway I changed my approach to the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the other way round, via JS (using jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".muted").html(getGenericObjName("{{n.news_type}}",{{n.news.object_id}}));
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<span class="muted"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<span class="muted">
   <script>
       //Here I want to add the string returned to outer span. (I also use jinja tags) 
       document.write(getGenericObjName("{{n.news_type}}",{{n.news.object_id}}));
   </script>
</span>
```

If you are already using jQuery a better solution might be:

```
<span class="muted"></span>

<script>
 //Here I want to add the string returned to outer span. (I also use jinja tags) 
$('.muted').html(getGenericObjName("{{n.news_type}}",{{n.news.object_id}}));
</script>
```

In this case don't put the javascript inside/before the span because it will be called before the span is in the DOM.

Comment: document.write() replaces the document contents.